# striping php file extension

Tags: php, file-extension

I've got some code of the form:

```
$linktarget="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?p=".urlencode($photos[$photonum]).$query;

$prev="<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pn=".($photonum-(($rows*$cols)*2)).$query."'>&lt;&lt; Previous</a>";

$photopage[]=$pagedivider"<a href='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?pn=".($pagelink).$query."'>$pagenum</a>;

$thumbsurl=dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/".$album;
```

Is there a way to keep the code as is but to strip the file extension (.php)? I've tried using variations of `$thumbsurl=dirname.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/".$album;` but that's not working.

Little help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove all the .php extensions? For example www.example.com/test.php -> www.example.com/test OR you want just to remove the .php from specific variable?

Comment: Preferably get rid of all the .php extensions. Not sure how I can do it since many of the links are of the form: filename.php?anchorsandstuff

Comment: You can do that by editing .htaccess file, it will remove the .php extension and "anchorandstuff" will continue to work. Search about .htaccess removeing .php extension, it's been answered many times!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php):

```
$thumbsurl=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, -4)."/".$album
```